# Does travel insurance covers hiking on high altitudes are participation in shamanic ceremonies?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, insurance, hiking, drugs

I think that general answer is: **"read the small print"**

I'll take my chances and ask if a generic travel insurance would cover:

1. hiking on Inca Trail? *(up to 4200m altitude)*
2. drinking ayahuasca? *(hallucinogenic drug)*

Both of the above are organised by specialised agencies who probably have own insurance but may require participants to sign a waiver.

It would be nice to know where to find insurance that would cover scenarios like **1)** and **2)**

Comment: I'd say "almost certainly (1)" and "probably not (2)", but yeah, read the small print. I just checked the last travel policy I purchased and one of the exclusions is *"The influence of alcohol or drugs (other than a drug administered 
or prescribed by a registered medical practitioner, and taken as 
prescribed)."* The only exclusions for hiking are for *"mountaineering necessitating the use of ropes"* and *"abseiling or outdoor rock climbing"*, neither of which are required for the Inca Trail.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), back when I was shopping around for insurance for a long trip which included a high-altitude trek in Nepal, most plans had some sort of altitude restriction in the fine print (though I don't remember what it typically was), or sometimes a very aggressive definition of "mountaineering". If I remember correctly some of them even offered an extra paid option to ease the restrictions. But I did manage to find a plan without such restrictions (it was Cigna, no idea whether their plan details are still the same). But short-trip plans may be less restrictive, I was only looking at long-term plans (i.e. travelling around a year).

As for (2), I don't know for sure, but I'm *guessing* you can find a plan that would only exclude *illegal* drugs. So if you manage to find such a plan, if the substance you're consuming is legal where you're consuming it, I don't think you should have a problem. But this is just my guess, I haven't actually tried finding such plans myself.

Answer (score 2):

> It would be nice to know where to find insurance that would cover scenarios like 1) and 2)

It's not a “generic” travel insurance but alpine clubs (e.g. [the German Alpine club](http://www.alpenverein.de/) or [Austrian Alpine club](http://www.alpenverein.at/portal/index.php)) offer insurance covering rescue and medical costs resulting from mountaineering accidents as part of their regular membership. The exact conditions differ a little but both also offer extra travel or “expedition” insurance for things not included in their regular insurance cover (mountaineering above 6000 or 7000 m, hard-to-reach areas like polar regions or Greenland, generic travel insurance, long-term travel).

For the DAV (German Alpine club), package tours abroad seem to be excluded but I see no similar restriction for ÖAV and they have [some info in English](http://aacuk.org.uk/) and a [“Britannia” chapter](http://www.alpenverein.at/portal/service/mitgliedschaft/membership-benefits.php) so I would look at the latter first (usually you would become a member of the chapter or *Sektion* for your locale and only incidentally of the national organization but I think it's also possible to become a member of the Austrian club directly). Membership fees are around €60-80, I don't know how this compares to the insurance products you were considering.

(I mentioned the clubs from German-speaking areas because the venerable British [Alpine Club](http://www.alpine-club.org.uk/) apparently does not offer insurance of any kind.)